Spring MVC : model object List<String> is not loaded correctly in JS
This is my first question on web site. the object wont load correctly. Problem only on List
Tried these and no success. Where am I Wrong? Thanks
1.
List<String> weekDayList= Arrays.asList("MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI");
model.addAttribute("weekDayList", weekDayList);




List<String> weekDayList = Arrays.asList("MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI");
weekDayList= Collections.singletonList(weekDayList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"))); // ['MON', ...]
model.addAttribute("weekDayList", weekDayList);

HTML:
   <script> var weekDayList = [[${weekDayList}]];</script>
   <script src="file.js"></script>

(also this)
<script> var weekDayList = "[[${weekDayList}]]";</script>
<script src="file.js"></script>

(and this)
<script type="text/javascript"> var weekDayList = "${weekDayList}";</script>
<script src="file.js"></script>


Inspect shows this:
var weekDayList = [&#39;MON&#39;, &#39;TUE&#39;, &#39;WED&#39;, &#39;THU&#39;, &#39;FRI&#39;];

